# Connect to node if it exists to prevent duplicate and redundant entries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an XML file that I trying to visualize using `Neo4j`. It looks like this:

```
<Organism>
 <Name>Bacillus halodurans C-125</Name>
  <Enzyme>M.BhaII</Enzyme>
   <Motif>GGCC</Motif>
  <Enzyme>M1.BhaI</Enzyme>
   <Motif>GCATC</Motif>
  <Enzyme>M2.BhaI</Enzyme>
   <Motif>GCATC</Motif>
</Organism>
```

My create query in cypher looks like this(below) which yields the required nodes and the edges I want :

```
CREATE (halodurans:Organism { name: "Bacillus halodurans C-125" })
CREATE (halodurans_e1:Enzyme { name: "M.BhaII" })
CREATE (halodurans_m1:Motif { name: "GGCC" })
CREATE (halodurans_e2:Enzyme { name: "M1.BhaI" })
CREATE (halodurans_m2:Motif { name: "GCATC" })
CREATE (halodurans_e3:Enzyme { name: "M2.BhaI" })
CREATE UNIQUE (halodurans)-[:HAS_ENZYME]->(halodurans_e1)
CREATE UNIQUE (halodurans)-[:HAS_ENZYME]->(halodurans_e2)
CREATE UNIQUE (halodurans)-[:HAS_ENZYME]->(halodurans_e3)
CREATE UNIQUE (halodurans_e1)-[:HAS_MOTIF]->(halodurans_m1)
CREATE UNIQUE (halodurans_e2)-[:HAS_MOTIF]->(halodurans_m2)
CREATE UNIQUE (halodurans_e3)-[:HAS_MOTIF]->(halodurans_m2)
```

However there are certain cases where a different `Organism` with a different `enzyme` has a  `motif` which already exists in the database. Instead of creating a new node , Id want that `enzyme` to connect to the `motif` node where it exists. Since i just started out in neo4j (roughly 6 hours ago) im not sure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace CREATE with MERGE. This will insert the node if none match the given properties, or MATCH it if it does.

Here's a [nice quick overview](http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/) of Cypher basics.

Comment: Do i replace all the `CREATE` with `MERGE` ?

Comment: Anytime there's any possibility the node already exists (and you want to prevent duplication), yes. Presumably all the enzymes here are unique, so it would be unnecessary for those.

Comment: I just tried it, and it keeps giving me this error `Invalid input '(': expected whitespace, comment, '=', node labels, MapLiteral, a parameter, a relationship pattern, ON, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 21, column 14) `. 

I am not returning anything because I just want to add the nodes and relationships